# How to spin an image infinitely in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to spin an image infinitely, a rotating disk.
I checked using *animated* or the *react-native-animatable*. They've got duration and timing, how do I rotate without putting a time or angle of spin to it.

```
  const handleAnimation = () => {
      Animated.timing(rotateAnimation, {
          toValue: 1,
          duration: 72000,
          useNativeDriver: false,
      }).start(() => {
          rotateAnimation.setValue(0);
      });
  }; 
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={async () => handleAnimation()}>
                <Animated.Image
                    style={{
                        width: 300,
                        height: 300,
                        transform: [{ rotate: interpolateRotating }]
                    }}
                    source={abcd} >
                </Animated.Image>
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: hmm, what about loop? 
https://reactnative.dev/docs/animated#loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the **Animated.timing** in a **Animated.loop**

```
Animated.loop(
    Animated.timing(rotateAnimation, {
         toValue: 1,
         duration: 72000,
         useNativeDriver: false,
     })
).start();
```